# Users cannot follow groups in Flask (SQLAlchemy)

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

**Error:**

```
sqlalchemy.orm.exc.UnmappedColumnError
sqlalchemy.orm.exc.UnmappedColumnError: Can't execute sync rule for source column 'user.id'; mapper 'mapped class Group->group' does not map this column.  Try using an explicit `foreign_keys` collection which does not include destination column 'group_followers.group_followed_id' (or use a viewonly=True relation).
```

*I'm trying to build a system that users can follow groups.*

**Here is the error parts of code:**

```
group_followers = db.Table('group_followers',
    db.Column('group_follower_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('group.id')),
    db.Column('group_followed_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('group.id'))
)
```

```
class User(UserMixin, db.Model):
...
    group_followed = db.relationship(
            'Group', secondary = group_followers,
            primaryjoin = (group_followers.c.group_follower_id == id),
            secondaryjoin = (group_followers.c.group_followed_id == id),
            backref = db.backref('group_followers', lazy='dynamic'), lazy='dynamic')
...
    def group_follow(self, group):
           if not self.is_following(group):
                self.group_followed.append(group)
```

Comment: How have you created the relationship between "Group" and "User"? Sharing this part of your database schema might help us to understand what the issue could be, because your work here looks largely correct

Comment: I haven't written any other code related to this, except routes.

Comment: What I mean is there is code you have not shared when you add `...`. This is what I am referring to. If you do not have this, then maybe that is the issue. The two tables' schema need to be created and a relationship between them defined.

Comment: There are lines like `username = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True, nullable=False)` in the parts I don't share. I did not create a relationship between the 2 tables. How can i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to clearly define the schema of your two tables.

```py
class User(UserMixin, db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(64), index=True, unique=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), index=True, unique=True)
    password_hash = db.Column(db.String(128))
    groups = db.relationship('Group', backref='user', lazy='dynamic')
    
    def __repr__(self):
        return f'User {self.username}'
    
class Group(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    timestamp = db.Column(db.DateTime, index=True, default=datetime.utcnow)
    # You can add any other field you want
    # ...
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
```

Above, I have shown how to create a relationship from the perspective of a user using `db.relationship()`. To make this relationship, you will need to add a `ForeignKey()` in the table you want to reference. `user` in `db.ForeingKey(user.id)` refers to the `User` table.

The association table you have created above (`group_followers`) is not part of any models so add it outside any of the classes `User` and `Group`:

```py
group_followers = db.Table('group_followers',
    db.Column('group_follower_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('group.id')),
    db.Column('group_followed_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('group.id'))
)
```

Then, declare the many-to-many relationship in the `User`'s table:

```py
class User(UserMixin, db.Model):
...
    group_followed = db.relationship(
            'Group', secondary = group_followers,
            primaryjoin = (group_followers.c.group_follower_id == id),
            secondaryjoin = (group_followers.c.group_followed_id == id),
            backref = db.backref('group_followers', lazy='dynamic'), lazy='dynamic')

    def group_follow(self, group):
           if not self.is_following(group):
                self.group_followed.append(group)
```

Run your migrations to update and apply these changes:

```py
(venv)$ flask db migrate -m 'group followers'
(venv)$ flask db upgrade
```

This should work for a user who wants to follow a group. You can define other functions to `unfollow` a group or check whether a user is already following a group.